# The DisplayPort PCB footprint I'm looking for doesn't exist in KiCad

Tags: kicad, footprint, displayport

Sometimes when I search KiCad for a PCB footprint, I get no results. For example, "DisplayPort" (part number 472720001).

Edit: I'm happy to make the footprint myself, but I'd rather download an existing footprint to minimise human error and save time.

What is the best approach to take when the PCB footprint you're looking for does not exist in KiCad or other EDA?

Comment: Why not just make your own?

Comment: Sure, symbol is easy but the footprint requires more care. I imagine it'd save time to use an existing footprint rather than creating your own.

Comment: Footprints are specific to individual parts, so you should look for one for the DP connector you've bought, not a random included part (which probably won't match). Very often the manufacturer will provide you with footprints on their website or on the digikey or mouser catalog.

Comment: The components distributor (Farnell) did not provide a footprint. The part is Molex 472720024. I didn't find a footprint on Molex's website, but I found a footprint for that part on Ultra Librarian.

Comment: @NickBolton Making a footprint is easy too. You just use the dimensions on the manufacturer's datasheet.

Comment: Sure, making a footprint is easy. I think the tricky part is knowing how to read a Molex connector datasheet. Could you give me some pointers? e.g. Where does it specify the distance between the mounting pins? https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2696871.pdf

Comment: you should look into technical documents called "recommended footprint", "drawing" or "land pattern"

Comment: for instance, for your connector it's this document https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/472720001_sd.pdf

Comment: Oh that's great! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @NickBolton You want the link near the top of the datasheet, marked "Drawing (PDF)".

Comment: @Hearth Damn, sounds obvious now you point it out.

Comment: @NickBolton I don't blame you for having trouble though. Molex does things very differently from almost every other manufacturer. Most of them will send the drawing links to Digikey, Mouser, et al along with the datasheet, or just include the drawing as part of the datasheet; Molex insists on keeping the drawings on their own site and only giving this very unusually-formatted and largely unhelpful datasheet to distributors.

Comment: Thanks @Hearth, that helps.

Comment: P.S. you'll find that KiCAD footprints can be quite generic and even flat-out-wrong for certain components.  Part of this is because different vendors can use slightly different packages.  So if you submit this footprint, be sure to include the vendor info.  Suggest plotting the output as 1:1 PDF, print it at 100% scale, and measure each with a caliper to ensure everything will actually fit.  Will likely find an anomaly or two.

Comment: Yes I have noticed. I have found myself very recently only using KiCad footprints for standard footprints. After studying many HDMI and DP footprints, I can now see that there isn’t really a standard. Now I just get them from Mouser (seems to be the best place so far).

Comment: You can get a lot of lands from the snapeda website, I’ve used it to great effect in the past.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks, checked it out, looks like a good one. I updated my answer to add SnapEDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, some components do not specifically use a standard footprint, and may differ slightly between manufacturers. According to some, the stock KiCad footprints might also be inaccurate. I tried to find an example for DisplayPort, but I actually couldn't find two DisplayPort footprints that differed from eachother (this is not to say an example does not exist). I do know of some footprints in particular that do certainly differ between manufacturers, e.g. Molex and Amphenol SMD HDMI connectors have totally different through-hole mounting pins:

[image: Molex HDMI]

Source: [Molex 471510001 drawing](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2008191734_MOLEX-471510001_C505243.pdf)

[image: Amphenol HDMI]

Source: [Amphenol 10029449 drawing](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Amphenol-ICC-10029449-111RLF_C427307.pdf)

**Option 1: Download the footprint**

These sites provide footprints for KiCad:

- [SnapEDA](https://www.snapeda.com/)
- [Component Search Engine](https://componentsearchengine.com/)
- [Octopart](https://octopart.com/)
- [Ultra Librarian](https://ultralibrarian.com)

Probably the most reliable place to get the footprint is the manufacturers website, if they offer them. Following the DisplayPort example, unfortunately Molex don't seem to provide footprint downloads (as far as I can see, not for the [472720001](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/io_connectors/0472720001) at least), though they do provide 3D model downloads (e.g. `.stm` for KiCad).

From my experience, Mouser/DigiKey, has a footprints download option for many components that they offer. So, if you're already on the site, then you might as well grab the footprint.

[image: Mouser footprint download]

**Option 2: Design your own footprint**

You may want to make your own footprint for two reasons:

1. If the footprint is not from the manufacturer website (e.g. if it is from SnapEDA), it's possible that there will be an error in the footprint; there is no guarantee of accuracy.
2. It's good practice; learning how to make accurate footprints from drawings is a valuable skill, and while you're checking the accuracy of a footprint, some would argue you may as well spend that time making your own.

Find the part specifications and measurements using terms like "recommended footprint", "drawing" or "land pattern", and create a PCB footprint using the KiCad footprint editor. Credit to Rahmany (in the comments) for that advice.

Something to bear in mind when looking for drawings: although the [472720001 datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2696871.pdf) itself doesn't mention the part dimensions, it does link to the [product customer drawing](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/472720001_sd.pdf), which does.

Comment: If there's a stock footprint in KiCad that's incorrect, report it to the bug tracker.